# Pattern matching on strings of different length

Tags: elixir

I have a list of strings:

```
 list1 = ["aaa_1_bbb_1326778", "aaa_629_bbb_37", "aaa_2254354_bbb_3997"]
```

How can I easily extract both numbers from each item except by using Regexp?

```
Enum.map(list1, fn(x) ->
  # 
end)
```

Is there any solution something like pattern matching?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the format is always 4 things separated by underscores and the second and fourth are integers, which are the things you want, I'd use `String.split` and pattern matching like this:

```
list1 = ["aaa_1_bbb_1326778", "aaa_629_bbb_37", "aaa_2254354_bbb_3997"]

Enum.map(list1, fn(x) ->
  [_, a, _, b] = String.split(x, "_")
  {String.to_integer(a), String.to_integer(b)}
end) |> IO.inspect
```

Output:

```
[{1, 1326778}, {629, 37}, {2254354, 3997}]
```

---

While you could use more pattern matching and less splitting here, you'd need to define some functions and use recursion, which I wouldn't personally do as long as `String.split` exists and fits the use case.

Comment: thanks, how can I create a map out of 2 variables? this doesn't work `%{a1, b1}`, and neither this `%{^a1, b1}`

Comment: Maps need to have keys specified, so something like `%{a: a1, b: b1}`